# Couldn't load GLMapCore: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, opengl-es, esri

Im getting this Error when loading an ESRI map inside the Android Environment.  This didn't happen with ESRI's .1 Alpha SDK, but it does happen with their 1.0.0 SDK.

I know it has something to do with the OpenGL lib, but can't seem to find a solution.  I am running the Motorola Xoom Tablet with the latest Android environment..

Also Its using Fragments, so that might have something to do with it.

Here is my stack Dump

```
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{c.map.EsriMapWidget}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1818)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at .map.EsriMapFragment.onCreateView(EsriMapFragment.java:21)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:714)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:990)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:257)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at .map.EsriMapWidget.onCreate(EsriMapWidget.java:155)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     ... 11 more
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     ... 31 more
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     ... 34 more
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     ... 36 more
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load GLMapCore: findLibrary returned null
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     at com.esri.android.map.Layer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370):     ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix for me was to open a sample ArcGIS app (in Eclipse, File > New > Other > ArcGIS for Android > ArcGIS Samples for Android) and copy the lib folder to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Different solution that worked for me:  Right click on the project and select 'ArcGIS Tools -> Conver to ArcGIS for Android project'.  Then Right click again and this time select 'ArcGIS Tools -> Fix Project Properties'.